# What could cause missing rows when importing data into Sequelize + Heroku Postgres?

Tags: node.js, excel, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using Heroku Postgres for a project and am trying to import excel spreadsheets (.xlsx) of data into a Postgres database. I have written a script in Node.js using the "xlsx" package and the "sequelize" packages. Basically, I read the excel file and convert the sheet to JSON, and then I loop through each object (row of data) in the json list and insert it into the database using Sequelize.

The issue is that after successfully running my script, there is about 800 missing rows of data that was not inserted into the database. 800 missing rows is about 20% of the total number of rows in the excel sheet.

I have done some extensive googling, but I can't seem to find any information related to missing rows when importing excel sheets into a database. If I had to guess, Sequelize does some "internal magic" to verify the integrity of data such as checking for duplicates or similar things of that nature, which might be eliminating rows. Unfortunately, the logs and print statements from sequelize are quite large and verbose, so it is hard to parse for what might be the issue, if the issue even is with sequelize.

Any information is appreciated!

Comment: How can I better formulate my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Show us your sequelize model, and an example of the input data. You say you are having trouble reading the sequelize logs, yet they likely have the answer to your question. Find the juicy parts.

Comment: Please provide the code used to insert to Db atleast